# How to select an item from "ng-select" dropdown list?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape using  the following website "https://maroof.sa/businesses" **python-selenium**.

on the left side there are 2 dropdown lists in which the items should be selected...

[image: dropdown lists]

i tried many time by different ways to select an item using select_by_visible_text
some time with click()
always get an error

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Navigate to the URL
driver.get(url="https://maroof.sa/businesses")
# Get the HTML content of the page
html = driver.page_source

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ng-select#select1')

print(dropdown.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
time.sleep(5)
dropdown.click()
time.sleep(3)
```

i use the print function to ensure that i am at the right plcae
and use time function to delay the code for some while until the page loads

finally i searched alot and finally found thag ng-select is angularJS which has a specific way to be selected using selenium, which i failed to know
so can you help ne selecting "سيارات" from the first dropdown and "اكسسوارات سيارات" from the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement function, that scrolls to dropdown, clicks on dropdown, selects from opened items container item with your text and waits for container (or item) to disappear.

Also, before and after selection loader is appeared, so you should wait for it's invisibility.

Scrolling to your case (at least to the first dropdown) is mandatory as far as it is fully rendering condition.

```py
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url="https://maroof.sa/businesses")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.maximize_window()

def select_dropdown_option_by_text(open_locator, item_locator, text):
    dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(open_locator))
    driver.execute_script("""
    arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
    """
    , dropdown)
    wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(dropdown)

    dropdown.click()
    options = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(item_locator))
    for option in options:
        if text in option.get_attribute('innerText'):
            option.click()
            break
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(options[0]))

options_selector = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[role=listbox] [role=option]')
search_blocks = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.search-block')))

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.loader-wrapper')))
select_dropdown_option_by_text((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#select1 .ng-arrow-wrapper'), options_selector, 'سيارات')

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.loader-wrapper')))
select_dropdown_option_by_text((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#select2 .ng-arrow-wrapper'), options_selector, 'إكسسوارات السيارات')
```